# Google Sheets - IF multiple cells match THEN copy third cell to a fourth cell

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets

[Example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YtKhZ5C3KFEl18-d6_FAYuA8XXFQejcsIGtKudibdbo/edit?usp=sharing) should, hopefully, be clear, but what I want is to combine an if/else with an AND-formular.

If a pupils name exist AND the pupil has solved i.e. subject 1 THEN copy the result to another cell on sheet 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In sheet 'JPV' I entered in B2

```
=ArrayFormula(if(len($A$2:$A), iferror(vlookup(B$1&$A$2:$A, {Solution2!$A:$A&Solution2!$C:$C, Solution2!$I:$I}, 2, 0)),))
```

and filled to the right. See if that works for you?

Comment: Absolutely brilliant! Thank You :-)